# How to add newsletter subscription in customer grid in admin

Tags: magento-1.9

How to add newsletter subscription in customer grid in admin?

If customer is subscribed newsletter then it should show **subscribed/unsubscribed** status in column.

I rewrite the module in my local folder

Answer (score 0):

here i guess if you successful add grid in customer grid you can try to use renderer

like below

```
class Namespace_Yourmodule_Block_Customerrenderer extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{   
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $customerId =  $row->getId(); // get customer id here

        $subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->load($customerId);
        if ($subscriber->getId()) {
            return "subscribed";
        }
        return "unsubscribe";
    }
}
```

call rendere in your attach column grid like below

```
$this->addColumn('newsletter_subscribe', array(
'header' => $this->__('newsletter subscribe'),
    'align'  => 'center',
    'renderer'  => 'Namespace_Yourmodule_Block_Customerrenderer'
));
```

i am sure it will worth for you. its just idea not whole code.